# Stuck retrieving dynamic column in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I had a custom field where user can insert text into it and thus change the database column name.

One of my pages function is to retrieve the value inside the custom column.The problem that I facing now is that i unable to retrieve the value.
For your information, I already create a function to get the name of the column.

In normal cases, i retrieve the value like this.

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $companys[$i]['check_existing_user'] = $row['id'];
 }
```

But for the dynamic one, I try to do something like this but it still wouldn't work.

```
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         $custom_field_1 = '\'customized_field_name("custom_field_1")\''; // return the column name and look like this -> 'custom_field_1'
         $companys[$i]['custom_field_1'] = $row[$custom_field_1];
                        $i++;
  }
```

I feel that the way I directly insert the variable is wrong but then I don't know what else i should do. Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: `I had a custom field where user can insert text into it and thus change the database column name.` - **WHY???**

Comment: @YourCommonSense because of the lack of you.

Comment: My company need it as it give the user flexibility to have their own column name in the form. I just follow order.

Comment: You should make it differently then. Don't change the column name in the database. Make a table `custom_column_names` with those columns and the value being the custom name, and a foreign key for each user. Changing column names will f**k everything up.

Comment: you should have stored these names in your application data, not in the column names.

Answer (score 0):

if it's a PHP function you are talking about, then you have to call it **like a PHP function:**

```
$companys[$i]['custom_field_1'] = $row[customized_field_name("custom_field_1")];
```

or better first store the custom name in a variable and then use

```
$custom_field_1 = customized_field_name("custom_field_1");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $companys[]['custom_field_1'] = $row[$custom_field_1];
}
```